# When a method that returns a bitmap fails, how to deal with this?

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm working on some code which fills a GridView full of images that have been pulled from YouTube. Now its working apart from when it can't find an image, I'm not sure why it can't find the image as the image link works in a browser but this actually works to my advantage as it weeds out videos that have been removed due to copyright/account closure etc.

My code to get the image is as follows

Call

```
        final Object item = allMatches.get(position);
        if(item != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap("http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/"+ allMatches.get(position).toString() + "/default.jpg"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else { imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default1)); }
```

loadBitmap()

```
    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) 
  {
      Bitmap bitmap = null;
      InputStream in = null;
      BufferedOutputStream out = null;

      try {
          in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(),  4 * 1024);

          final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream,  4 * 1024);

          int byte_;
          while ((byte_ = in.read()) != -1)
              out.write(byte_);
          out.flush();

          final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
          BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
          //options.inSampleSize = 1;

          bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("","Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
      } finally {
          try{
              in.close();
              out.close();
          }catch( IOException e )
          {
              System.out.println(e);
          }
      }
      return bitmap;
```

So this will sometimes crash with the following Stacktrace

```
03-23 01:47:10.087: E/(9757): Could not load Bitmap from: http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/8s3lnGuyC9M/default.jpg
03-23 01:47:10.247: W/dalvikvm(9757): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at com.myapp.Sample.loadBitmap(Sample.java:159)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at com.myapp..Sample$ImageAdapter.getView(Sample.java:207)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1467)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:935)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:843)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I need to do is just be able to deal with it not being able to retrieve the image. My Java skills are limited but I want something like the below (but actually working)

```
Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap("http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/"+ allMatches.get(position).toString() + "/default.jpg"); //  

if (bitmap == null) {
   imageView.setImageBitmap(defaultBitmap); 
} else {
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); }
```

or

```
//Doesn't work anyway due to 'Exception IOException is not compatible with throws clause in Adapter.getView'
try { 
Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap("http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/"+ allMatches.get(position).toString() + "/default.jpg"); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}catch( IOException ) {
imageView.setImageBitmap(defaultBitmap);
}
```

My understanding of try catch blocks is that if you 'catch the error' the code should continue. In this case shouldn't it just be printing the error to the log and carrying on?

How can I do this for when 'loadBitmap' fails at retrieving the image?

EDIT: I have updated the code as per some user comments - it still provides the exact same error, it just removes some doubt around the point of failure. Also, to clarify

```
Line 159: in.close();
Line 207: Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap("http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/"+ allMatches.get(position).toString() + "/default.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
try
{
    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap("http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/"+ allMatches.get(position).toString() + "/default.jpg"); 
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.err.println("Couldn't load image: "+e.getMessage());
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default1)); 
}
```

Second:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) throws IOException
{
    final InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(),  4 * 1024);

    try 
    {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream,  4 * 1024);

        try
        {
            int byte_;
            while ((byte_ = in.read()) != -1)
                out.write(byte_);
            out.flush();

            final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.inSampleSize = 1;

            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
        }
        finally
        {
            out.close();
        }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I'm not sure how to PM on here but I'll happily send you $5 for a beer/coffee through Paypal if you message it to me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

```
catch (IOException e) 
{
    Log.e("","Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    // If IOExceotion occurs, the `bitmap` variable is null, right?
    bitmap = bitmap.loadBitmap("http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/k4v9JWUhveY/default.jpg");
    //       ^^^^^^ NullPointerException will be thrown and IOException will be lost (overwritten by NullPointerException).
}
```

Comment: allMatches is definitely not null as I added one entry to it for testing. Each time the app crashes it saves a log of the image url it couldn't find, so when something like http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/default.jpg/default.jpg happens it will always crash (when loadBitmap fails at loading a bitmap), and these values are fed to it through allMatches. Btw, when trying your code I get 'The method concat(String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder'

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I found the error and corrected the post.

Comment: Thanks again. Are you referring to 'bitmap = bitmap. loadBitmap("http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/k4v9JWUhveY/default.jpg");'? Even with removing this completely and checking if it is null in my getView gives the same error.

Comment: OK. If you fix bitmap.loadBitmap(...), then `loadBitmap` will return null when IOException thrown, right? And then `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` will throw new NullPointerException. I think the better way is to delete `catch` block, declare `thrown IOException` in `loadBitmap` declaration and wrap `Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap(...); imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` if a `try` block. I hope I'm clear explaining :)

Comment: I have also tried this, unfortunately loadBitmap is being called in a different class ('ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter') so when I try to add 'throws' to my getView method I get: Exception IOException is not compatible with throws clause in Adapter.getView(int, View, ViewGroup). So many hurdles! Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say the same as edthethird. You should avoid catching an `Exception` when possible. You say it is not working, so could you tell us which are the lines 159 and 207 of you `Sample.java` class, where the NullPointerException occured ? It would be of great help to understand the problem.

Where does this line point to ? It doesn't seem like you quote it in you question:

```
03-23 01:47:10.267: E/AndroidRuntime(9757):     at com.myapp..Sample$ImageAdapter.getView(Sample.java:207)
```

And why don't you set the default image as a local drawable instead of pulling it from a website ?

Comment: 157 = in.close(); (in finally { try { within loadBitmap(). 207 is the call to loadBitmap (Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap(....). I have also tried setting the drawable to a local resource but I think its failing due to loadBitmap when it freaks out due to a bad link and doesn't seem to continue.